# How to fix TextBox height

Tags: c#, textbox, height

When I change the font size ,the height of the TextBox also changes. So, how can I change the font size without changing the TextBox height?

here is my code:

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Can you tell us what language you're working with?

Comment: add your code for better understand.

Comment: It's C#.. Sorry because I didn't mention the programming language.

Comment: asking without code is more diffucult to answer your question . :>

Comment: I didn't use a code, just from property box

Comment: Is this WPF or in a web page? We really need more information to help you.

Comment: WinForm? [TextBoxBase.AutoSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.autosize?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using WPF:

you can simply make a TextBox and set the Height to a Value you want. If you then change the FontSize, the Height wont change.

```
<TextBox
        Text="test"
        Height="20"
        FontSize="20"/>
```

This will look like the following:

[image: FontSize bigger than TextBox Height]

EDIT:

For WinForms:

Simply set the "Multiline" Property to True.
Then you are able to Change the Height Property, even if your TextBox is smaller than your Text in it.